# builder is depreacated and shouldn't be used Flutter Provider

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-provider

How to fix this issue? I tried to add `create` and How do I pass these parameters?

```
  ProxyProvider<YelloChatDb, UserDao>(
    builder: (context, yelloChatDb, userdAO) => UserDao(yelloChatDb),
  ),

  ProxyProvider<YelloVendorClient, VendorService>(
      builder: (context, yelloVendorClient, categoryService) =>
          VendorService.create(yelloVendorClient.chopperClient),
      dispose: (context, categoryService) => categoryService.client.dispose()),
```

**Dao class**

```
@UseDao(tables: [Users])
class UserDao extends DatabaseAccessor<YelloChatDb> with _$UserDaoMixin {
  UserDao(YelloChatDb db) : super(db);

...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change log 3.2.0 https://pub.dev/packages/provider#320 
**Deprecated "builder" of providers in favor to "create"** 
You can use `create` instead of `builder` 
example from https://pub.dev/packages/provider#proxyprovider 
code snippet

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return MultiProvider(
    providers: [
      ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_) => Counter()),
      ProxyProvider<Counter, Translations>(
        create: (_, counter, __) => Translations(counter.value),
      ),
    ],
    child: Foo(),
  );
}
```